# Roboclaw : [ERROR] : cmd: 59 failed crc_check

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros, robotics

I have a problem with my robot. Whenever I try to launch it, I keep getting an error message: [ERROR] cmd:59 failed crc_check (and sometimes [ERROR] cmd:49 failed crc_check).

Although I can see the roboclaw_node in the rqt_graph, but I am unable to send any commands to the motors.
I have a Roboclaw ST 2x45A with the correct configuration.
Can someone please help me identify the problem and suggest a solution?

For the execution and the error I have this:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/bno055_node.py", line 165, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/bno055_node.py", line 136, in main
    node = BNO055Driver()
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/bno055_node.py", line 28, in __init__
    if not self.device.begin():
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 382, in begin
    self._config_mode()
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 358, in _config_mode
    self.set_mode(OPERATION_MODE_CONFIG)
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 416, in set_mode
    self._write_byte(BNO055_OPR_MODE_ADDR, mode & 0xFF)
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/Adafruit_BNO055/BNO055.py", line 302, in _write_byte
    self._i2c_device.write8(address, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 116, in write8
    self._bus.write_byte_data(self._address, register, value)
  File "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 256, in write_byte_data
    self._device.write(data)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
[ INFO] [1658396096.440849967]: Done initializing likelihood field model.
[bno055_driver-2] process has died [pid 1770, exit code 1, cmd /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/drivers/ros_bno055_driver/nodes/bno055_node.py __name:=bno055_driver __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/5d988550-08d8-11ed-b5aa-e3ef9a600f4e/bno055_driver-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/5d988550-08d8-11ed-b5aa-e3ef9a600f4e/bno055_driver-2*.log
[WARN] [1658396097.779578]: EXTERNAL_PID expected
[WARN] [1658396097.822070]: Roboclaw Firmware "'USB Roboclaw 2x45a v4.2.8\\n'"
[WARN] [1658396097.833447]: M1 PID 0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
[WARN] [1658396097.837850]: M2 PID 0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000
[WARN] [1658396097.848505]: M1MaxCurrent 10.00 A M2MaxCurrent 10.00 A triggered after 0.200000 s
[ERROR] [1658396098.954525]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396098.962611]: Main batt voltage high hysteresis
[WARN] [1658396098.967473]: M1 over current
[WARN] [1658396098.982044]: M2 over current
[WARN] [1658396098.991308]: Main batt voltage high
[ERROR] [1658396099.001628]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.006135]: End of : Main batt voltage high hysteresis
[WARN] [1658396099.011149]: End of : M1 over current
[WARN] [1658396099.017205]: End of : M2 over current
[WARN] [1658396099.024713]: End of : Main batt voltage high
[ERROR] [1658396099.032435]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.039953]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ WARN] [1658396099.046330150]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.100352 timeout was 0.1.
[ERROR] [1658396099.054249]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.068091]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.093577]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.119525]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.147087]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.167921]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.193518]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.222741]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame base_footprint at time 1658396099.246406 according to authority unknown_publisher
         at line 280 in /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame base_footprint at time 1658396099.246406 according to authority unknown_publisher
         at line 280 in /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp
Warning: TF_REPEATED_DATA ignoring data with redundant timestamp for frame base_footprint at time 1658396099.246406 according to authority unknown_publisher
         at line 280 in /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/geometry2/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp
[ WARN] [1658396099.256928502]: global_costmap: Parameter "plugins" not provided, loading pre-Hydro parameters
[ERROR] [1658396099.258143]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.268142]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.293706]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ INFO] [1658396099.319486335]: global_costmap: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ERROR] [1658396099.320640]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.352751]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ INFO] [1658396099.357522298]: Requesting the map...
[ERROR] [1658396099.367956]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.393685]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.418762]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.455218]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.467973]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.497122]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.518128]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.553966]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.568980]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ INFO] [1658396099.575256002]: Resizing costmap to 2048 X 2048 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ERROR] [1658396099.592809]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.617774]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.647493]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ INFO] [1658396099.666048372]: Received a 2048 X 2048 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ERROR] [1658396099.668508]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ INFO] [1658396099.682784391]: global_costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ERROR] [1658396099.694193]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ INFO] [1658396099.701562409]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser_scan_sensor
[ERROR] [1658396099.719585]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.744177]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ INFO] [1658396099.767514632]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ERROR] [1658396099.768384]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.793876]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.819689]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.848546]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.868187]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.894135]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.930328]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check
[ERROR] [1658396099.945882]: cmd: 59 failed crc_check```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.